# Traverse folder permissions not working

Tags: permissions, security-trimming

When assigning permissions to a subfolder, the traverse (limited access) permission isn't working properly, the parent folder isn't view-able from the root of the document library.

- Document Library

  - Parent Folder

    - Folder A

      - File A
    - Folder B
    - File X

The goal is to give permission to a user to view all files under Folder A only. Not access to view Folder B or File X.

So the contribute permission is set on Folder A for the user. SharePoint then assigns the Limited Access permission to the Parent Folder and Document Library so the user can traverse from the Document Library into Folder A.
This currently does not work, as the Parent Folder does not display. Folder A can be viewed directly via a direct link.

Any tips why?

If I assign the read permission to the parent folder, you can of course view the folder from the document library root, but youc an also view Folder B and File X - this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.krichie.com/2012/04/02/sharepoint-item-level-security-means-nothing-to-the-blob-cache-with-anonymous-access/

stop inheriting top level permissions to SharePoint Folder then after Remove unwanted User Groups or Users. Read Link it helps......

Comment: I've already disabled permission inheritance to add the permissions at the folder level.

Comment: Stop inheritance at Folder A level not at Parent Folder Level, in this case go with item level Inheritance so Folder A is also a item

Comment: Inheritance is stopped at folder A so that we can assign the permission there. The Parent Folder has inheritance disabled also as thats how the library is set up, I will set up a test library and keep the inheritance enabled on the Parent Folder to see if that changes anything - though if it does it still isn't a viable solution.